# How to convert list of strings to their correct Python types?

Tags: python

Given a list of python strings, how can I automatically convert them to their correct type?

Meaning, if I have:

```
["hello", "3", "3.64", "-1"]
```

I'd like this to be converted to the list

```
["hello", 3, 3.64, -1]
```

where the first element is a string, the second an int, the third a float, and the fourth an int.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import ast

L = ["hello", "3", "3.64", "-1"]

def tryeval(val):
  try:
    val = ast.literal_eval(val)
  except ValueError:
    pass
  return val

print [tryeval(x) for x in L]
```

Comment: In honesty, this is a better solution than mine.

Comment: but evals are kinda hackish and overpowered

Comment: If it's good enough for the Python compiler, then it's good enough for the user.

Comment: you are correct, I was ignorant of the safe semantics of `ast.literal_eval` *bows*

Comment: Note that this does note work for cases like '01', where int('01')==1, but literal_eval throws an error. Depending on the use case, that means literal_eval isn't enough

Comment: Some others which throw `SyntaxError` instead of `ValueError` e.g. `*` and `+`, so probably worth it to `except SyntaxError` and `pass` too.

Answer (score 8):

Without using evaluation:

```
def convert(val):
    constructors = [int, float, str]
    for c in constructors:
        try:
            return c(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: Great solution (and safe!). The approach can easily be extended to any data type. +1

Comment: @Escualo not quite, a counter example would be the boolean type.

Answer (score 4):

I accomplished the same using `json.loads` method

```
def f(l):
    for i in l:
        try:
            yield json.loads(i)
        except:
            yield i
```

Test:

```
In [40]: l
Out[40]: ['hello', '3', '3.64', '-1']

In [41]: list(f(l))
Out[41]: ['hello', 3, 3.64, -1]
```

Comment: For my task, this method is much better than the other one using ast lib. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
def tryEval(s):
  try:
    return eval(s, {}, {})
  except:
    return s

map(tryEval, ["hello", "3", "3.64", "-1"])
```

Only do this if you trust the input.  Also, be aware that it supports more than just literals; arithmetic expressions will be evaluated as well.

Comment: You should specify exception types (i.e. NameError, SyntaxError).

Comment: In general, yes, but in this implementation, definitely not.  Do you really want to attempt the task of determining *all* exceptions that can possibly be raised by `eval`?  ZeroDivisionError, TypeError, and probably some more that even I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

If the you are truly interested in only strings, floats, and ints, I prefer the more verbose, less-evalful

```
def interpret_constant(c):
    try:
        if str(int(c)) == c: return int(c)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        if str(float(c)) == c: return float(c)
    except ValueError:
        return c

test_list = ["hello", "3", "3.64", "-1"]

typed_list = [interpret_constant(x) for x in test_list]
print typed_list
print [type(x) for x in typed_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but I wanted to point out how important this can be when you have a database of parameters with schema `ID`,  `PAR`,  `VAL`. For instance:

```
ID  PAR      VAL
001 velocity '123.45'
001 name     'my_name'
001 date     '18-dec-1978'
```

This schema is appropriate when you don't know how many parameters you need to store for a certain `ID`. The disadvantage is precisely that the values in `VAL` are all strings, and need to be converted to the correct data type on demand. You can do this by adding a fourth column to the schema, called `TYPE`, or you can use any of the approaches proposed thus far.

Good question!

PS. The database schema is related to [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725568/how-to-structure-normalize-a-database-of-physical-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

A variant of ryans's nice solution, for numpy users:

```
def tonum( x ):
    """ -> int(x) / float(x) / None / x as is """
    if np.isscalar(x):  # np.int8 np.float32 ...
    # if isinstance( x, (int, long, float) ):
        return x
    try:
        return int( x, 0 )  # 0: "0xhex" too
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float( x )  # strings nan, inf and -inf too
        except ValueError:
            if x == "None":
                return None
            return x

def numsplit( line, sep=None ):
    """ line -> [nums or strings ...] """
    return map( tonum, line.split( sep ))  # sep None: whitespace
```