# formatting string to dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So I am trying to format a string to a dict.
Meaning, I receive an str input of this sort:

```
"b:0.1 a:0.5 n:0.2 p:0.1 c:0.1 k:0.1"
```

And wish to convert it to dict:

```
{'b':0.1,'a':0.5,'n':0.2 and so on... 'k':0.1}
```

So far I did the exact opposite:

```
def string_to_ngram_dict(x):
    y = {"{!s}:{!r}".format(key, val) for (key, val) in x.items()}
```

input:

```
{ “b”: 0.1, “a”: 0.4, “n”: 0.2, “p”: 0.1, “c”: 0.1, “k”: 0.1 }
```

output:

```
"b:0.1 a:0.5 n:0.2 p:0.1 c:0.1 k:0.1”
```

So I was wondering if there is any cool trick to reverse this function I wrote. If not, any ideas on how to to do it?

Thanks

Comment: by 'obvious' do you mean 'opposite'?

Comment: Don't use such an inconvenient format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split()` and the fact that `dict([('k1','v1'), ])` makes a `dict` properly:

```
s = "b:0.1 a:0.5 n:0.2 p:0.1 c:0.1 k:0.1"
dict([i.split(':') for i in s.split()])
```

```
{'b': '0.1', 'a': '0.5', 'n': '0.2', 'p': '0.1', 'c': '0.1', 'k': '0.1'}
```

you could convert the types later depend on your need. In general type conversion from `str` is not a good idea as it is unsafe.

Comment: You can use this for-loop to convert all the values to floats:

 `for key in test.keys():        
        test[key] = float(test[key])`

Comment: @M-Chen-3 or `{k: float(d[k]) for k in d}` where d is the dict output

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split()` and `dict()`

```
splitStr = 'b:0.1 a:0.5 n:0.2 p:0.1 c:0.1 k:0.1'.split(' ')

strList = []

for s in splitStr :
    strList.append(s.split(':'))
    
dict(strList)
```

```
{'b': '0.1', 'a': '0.5', 'n': '0.2', 'p': '0.1', 'c': '0.1', 'k': '0.1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8819/ryan)'s [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859738/11789440) for type conversion. This will not automatically type all values. It may be fun to play around this, but I do not recommend using it in any serious code (use json instead).

```
mydict = {}
for i in mystring.split(" "):
    x = i.split(":")
    mydict[x[0]] = convert(x[1])
```

Ryan's `convert` is:

```
def convert(val):
    constructors = [int, float, str]
    for c in constructors:
        try:
            return c(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by " " (space)

str.split( )

Then loop through list and populate a dictionary