# How to have preserve quotes if the value is a character and remove the quotes if it is a number when creating a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to convert any string in the format

```
"var1=var a;var2=var b"
```

to a dictionary and I managed to do that as follows.

```
a = "a=b;b=2"

def str_to_conf_dict(input_str):
    return dict(u.split('=') for u in input_str.split(';'))

b = str_to_conf_dict(a)
```

```
result= {'a': 'b', 'b': '2'}
```

But the values in the dictionary have quotes regardless whether `var a`, `var b` is a number or an alphabet.

I know that the values are always going to be a mix of characters and numbers (int/float/negatives). How would I have the quotes if the variable is a character and remove the quotes if it is a number?

It is crucial to have the quotes only on characters because I will pass the values to functions which work specifically if it meets the criteria, there is no way to modify that end.

Comment: loop through the dictionary, and use `try` `except` , if it will fail, it will go to the `except` block, where you will do nothing, and keep the character as is, and if successful, it becomes a number, reference : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *separate* function for converting the value to its proper type.

Take a look at [How to convert list of strings to their correct Python types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2859674/2745495), where the answers use either [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) or [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) (amongst other solutions) to deserialize a string to a suitable Python object:

```py
import json

def convert(val):
    try:
        return json.loads(val)
    except ValueError:
        return val  # return as-is
```

Then apply that function on each of the values from the original string.

```py
def str_to_conf_dict(input_str):
    d = {}
    for pair in input_str.split(";"):
        k, v = pair.split("=")
        d[k] = convert(v)
    return d

s = "a=b;b=2;c=-3;d=xyz;e=4ajkl;f=3.14"
print(str_to_conf_dict(s))
```

```
{'a': 'b', 'b': 2, 'c': -3, 'd': 'xyz', 'e': '4ajkl', 'f': 3.14}
```

All the numbers (ints, floats, and negative ones) should be converted to numbers, while others are retained as-is (as strings, with quotes).

If you want to (*unnecessarily*) force it into a one-liner (for some reason), you'll need to setup a `{key : convert(value)}` dictionary comprehension. You can either `.split` twice to get each item of the pair:

```py
def str_to_conf_dict(input_str):
    return {
        pair.split('=')[0]: convert(pair.split('=')[1])
        for pair in input_str.split(';')
    }
```

Or pair up the items from the `.split('=')` output. You can take inspiration from the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from the `itertools` package, or implement something simpler if you know the format is always going to be `key=val`:

```py
def get_two(iterable):
    yield iterable[0], iterable[1]

def str_to_conf_dict(input_str):
    return { 
        k: convert(v) 
        for pair in input_str.split(';') 
        for k, v in get_two(pair.split('='))
    }
```